# Upgrading from cordova-ios 5

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

Im trying to update my app from cordova-ios 5 to a new version. When I removed and added the IOS platform and built the app, the app showed the splash screen but after that showed only a white blank screen. I waited for a while but nothing happened. This similarly happened when I tried to upgrade the Android platform, but I found a solution [here](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/7891143965975-Migrating-to-Cordova-Android-11).

Is there any solution similar to that one? Should something be deleted, added or modified?